# Extremely low loss stays the same using Keras for CRNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to develop a CRNN with Keras. But when training the network my loss stays the same after about two iterations and additionally is extremely low! It can't be right, but I don't know my mistake, so I want to show you my model and my training and hope you guys can help me with that issue.

**That's the weird loss:**

```
1. Iteration:
Train: Loss: 4.596062183380127     accuracy: 0.34375

2. Iteration:
Train: Loss: 1.1920930376163597e-07     accuracy: 0.453125

3. Iteration:
Train: Loss: 1.1920930376163597e-07     accuracy: 0.53125

4. Iteration:
Train: Loss: 1.1920930376163597e-07     accuracy: 0.5625

5. Iteration:
Train: Loss: 1.1920930376163597e-07     accuracy: 0.484375
```

**This is my model:**

```
cnn_dropout = 0.3
rnn_dropout = 0.3
learning_rate = 0.001

n_units = 256
batch_size = 64
steps = 1000

strides = 3
kernel_size = 3
num_classes = 4

model = Sequential()

# CNN 2D
model.add(Convolution2D(n_units, strides=strides, kernel_size=kernel_size, batch_size=batch_size, input_shape=input_shape, padding='SAME', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(n_units, strides=strides, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(cnn_dropout))

model.add(Reshape((n_units, -1)))

model.add(LSTM(n_units, input_shape=(256, 147), return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(rnn_dropout))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(cnn_dropout))

opt = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

**This is my training phase:**

```
# Training the model
for n in range(1, steps):
    print("{}. Iteration:".format(n))

    x_train_batch, y_train_batch = next_batch(batch_size, train_feature_paths, train_labels_f0)

    score = model.train_on_batch(x_train_batch, y_train_batch)
    print("Train: Loss: {}     accuracy: {}".format(score[0], score[1]))

    # Test every 20 iterations
    if n % 100 == 0:
        x_test_batch, y_test_batch = next_batch(batch_size, test_feature_paths, test_labels_f0)

        score = model.test_on_batch(x_test_batch, y_test_batch)
        print("Test: Loss: {}     accuracy: {}".format(score[0], score[1]))
```

If you need to know, my input data are mel-spectrograms, which were extracted and stored as *.npy-files in advance. The shape of the stored mel-specs is (19, 128, 128).

I use tensorflow-gpu version 1.5.1 and Keras version 2.1.6

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you have a dropout layer after your final softmax. That doesn't make sense from a training perspective and is going to really limit your training accuracy.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now it doesn't stay the same and goes below 1. =) But the loss still starts with values greater than 1 and even after a while there are still some losses greater than 1 from time to time. If I'm right the loss should always be between 0 and 1, shouldn't it? Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: I don't think there's any property of cross entropy that constrains the loss to be between 0 and 1? The accuracy should be of course, but the range of the loss is pretty much just >= 0

Comment: Oh well then I got that wrong. Thank you again for the enlightenment! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a dropout layer after the final softmax layer essentially zeroes out the output layer, making your dropout percent effectively the percent chance you get it wrong, even given a perfect model! It also means that the final output will often not model a probability distribution (i.e. sum to 1) as the output of a softmax layer would, meaning that applying categorical crossentropy (which relies on the input being a probability distribution) will give very strange results (like 0s when they shouldn't be)